When is a Schrodinger equation equivalent to a Fokker-Planck equation?
In chap. 3 in these notes on kinetic theory, Tong shows that the Fokker-Planck operator for a particle undergoing overdamped Langevin dynamics in a potential $V$ is equivalent to a Schrodinger operator with potential $U$, with a seemingly nontrivial identification between the potentials:
\begin{align*}
U = -\frac{1}{2\gamma} \nabla^2 V + \frac{1}{4D\gamma^2} |\nabla V|^2\tag{3.43}
\end{align*}
Manifestly, if we have a potential $V$ in hand, we can construct the potential for the isomorphic Schrodinger equation by simply substituting our potential function into the above formula. Passing from $U$ to $V$ seems far less obvious, however, since it seemingly requires solving a nonlinear PDE.
My question is: under what conditions on $U$ does the above PDE have a solution for $V$? In other words, when we have a Schrodinger equation, in what cases is it isomorphic to a Langevin equation evolving in imaginary time?
(There is one obvious condition that will be necessary here, which is that the Hamiltonian in the Schrodinger equation should have ground state energy zero. This can be achieved by simply adding a constant to $U$, so really my question is: under what conditions can we take a Schrodinger equation, add some constant to the potential so that the ground state energy is zero, and identify this rescaled Schrodinger equation with the imaginary time evolution of some Langevin equation.)

In one dimension there is always a $V$ if the ground state has zero energy. Then the  equation $U(x)=\partial_x^2 V+(\partial_x V)^2$ is a
Riccati equation which is solved for $V(x)$ by finding the  ground state wavefunction
$$
(-\partial_x^2 +U)\psi=0,
$$
and writing $\psi(x)=e^{-V(x)}$.  This last writing is possible because the ground state has no places where $\psi(x)$ changes sign.
I have not thought about higher dimensions though!
